# Referencing another worksheet within a formula using the worksheet name

Tags: excel, testing, excel-formula, metrics

I'm using Excel for reporting/tracking test metrics. My sheet has several references to a range in another worksheet called '20th February', for example: 


`=COUNTIFS('20th February'!B:B, "Customer Care", '20th February'!E:E,"Pass")`

...and so on. There are about 35 cells like this.

Rather than having to change the date in each cell manually, I want the date to take reference from another cell in the same worksheet so I only have to change the date in one place.

So, if C1 contains the text `20th February` which is the name of another sheet, how can I incorporate that within the formulas above?

I think the issue is that the cell I'm referencing isn't being interpreted as a worksheet, but I thought `INDIRECT` does exactly that. I've looked into the `VLOOKUP` function as well, but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using `INDIRECT` is the correct approach, just make sure you get the syntax correct

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$C$1&"'"&"!B:B"), "Customer Care", INDIRECT("'"&$C$1&"'"&"!E:E"),"Pass")
```

So `INDIRECT("'"&$C$1&"'"&"!B:B")` is sticking together `'` + `February 20th` + `'!B:B`

Comment: Thank you, Tim - it's worked perfectly! That's one hell of a formula (for my simple mind)... I was a million miles away from the correct answer! Thanks again!